# Scraping multiple urls from a list of urls. Obtaining the data (text) behind each url, and writing out a text file

Tags: r, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am learning python (using 3.5). I realize I will probably take a bit of heat for posting my question. Here goes: I have literally reviewed several hundred posts, help docs, etc. all in an attempt to construct the code I need. No luck thus far. I hope someone can help me. I have a set of URLs say, 18 or more. Only 2 illustrated here:
[1] "http://www.senate.mo.gov/media/15info/Chappelle-Nadal/releases/111915.html"
[2] "http://www.senate.mo.gov/media/15info/Chappelle-Nadal/releases/092215.htm"

I need to scrape all the data (text) behind each url and write out to individual text files (one for each URL) for future topic model analysis. Right now, I pull in the urls through R using `rvest`. I then take each url (one at a time, by code) into python and do the following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://www.senate.mo.gov/media/14info/chappelle-nadal/Columns/012314-Condensed.html').read())
txt = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'body'})
print(soup.get_text())
#print(soup.prettify())  not much help
#store the info in an object, then write out the object
test=print(soup.get_text())
test=soup.get_text()  
#below does write a file
#how to take my BS object and get it in
open_file = open('23Jan2014cplNadal1.txt', 'w')
open_file.write(test)
open_file.close()
```

The above gets me partially to my target. It leaves me just a little clean up regarding the text, but that's okay. The problem is that it is labor intensive.

Is there a way to

1. Write a clean text file (without invisibles, etc.) out from R with all listed urls?
2. For python 3.5: Is there a way to take all the urls, once they are in a clean single file (the clean text file, one url per line), and have some iterative process retrieve the text behind each url and write out a text file for each URL's data(text) to a location on my hard drive?

I have to do this process for approximately 1000 state-level senators. Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Edit to original: Thank you so much all. To N. Velasquez: I tried the following:

```
urls<-c("http://www.senate.mo.gov/media/14info/Chappelle-Nadal/releases/120114.html",         
"http://www.senate.mo.gov/media/14info/Chappelle-Nadal/releases/110614.htm"          
)

for (url in urls) {
  download.file(url, destfile = basename(url), method="curl", mode ="w", extra="-k")
}
```

html files are then written out to my working directory. However, is there a way to write out text files instead of html files? I've read download.file info and can't seem to figure out a way to push out individual text files. Regarding the suggestion for a for loop: Is what I illustrate what you mean for me to attempt? Thank you!

Comment: I'm just curious: if you're getting all the urls in R with `rvest`, why don't you use it to do the rest? If you have the urls in R (I assume in a vector), you can loop through them and get all the texts like this (with `dplyr` loaded): `text <- read_html(url) %>% html_node('div.body')%>% html_text()`.

Comment: Note: http://www.senate.mo.gov/robots.txt

Comment: While what Oriol says is true, I would point that web scraping in R is one of those rare occasions when it is better to employ for-loops than vectorizations.
The reason is that if any particular url returns an error code [202, 404, etc..), the whole command tends to break down.
In fact, when web scraping or querying xml/json APIs, I often use Excel to automatically write as many lines of code as objects capturing a single url, and then I bind the resulting data frames. If you are capturing thousands of urls, this ensures general robustness.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for 1 is: Sure!
The following code will loop you through the html list and export atomic TXTs, as per your request. 
Note that through rvest and html_node() you could get a much more structure datset, with recurring parts of the html stored separately. (header, office info, main body, URL,  etc...)

```
library(rvest)
urls <- (c("http://www.senate.mo.gov/media/15info/Chappelle-Nadal/releases/111915.html", "http://www.senate.mo.gov/media/15info/Chappelle-Nadal/releases/092215.htm"))


for (i in 1:length(urls))
    {
     ht <- list()
     ht[i] <- html_text(html_node(read_html(urls[i]), xpath = '//*[@id="mainContent"]'), trim = TRUE)
     ht <- gsub("[\r\n]","",ht)
     writeLines(ht[i], paste("DOC_", i, ".txt", sep =""))
}
```

Look for the DOC_1.txt and DOC_2.txt in your working directory.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the code you suggested above, but get the error: Error: object 'ht' not found. I'm sure there is something very simple I should be doing, but am too blind to see it. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Object ht is created in the first command of the for-loop: ht[i] <- html_text(html_node....
My original posts required that the urls be contained in a list called "url_list". In your edited post, such list is called "urls". I have updated my post to reflect your naming..Give it another try, please.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I see---I should have caught that. Process: Closed R, reopened R, loaded only rvest. library(rvest)
urls <- (c("http://www.senate.mo.gov/media/15info/Chappelle-Nadal/releases/111915.html", "http://www.senate.mo.gov/media/15info/Chappelle-Nadal/releases/092215.htm"))


for (i in 1:length(urls))
{
  ht[i] <- html_text(html_node(read_html(urls[i]), xpath = '//*[@id="mainContent"]'), trim = TRUE)
  ht <- gsub("[\r\n]","",ht)
  writeLines(ht[i], paste("DOC_", i, ".txt", sep =""))
}    #I still get the error: Error: object 'ht' not found

Comment: You are most certainly right, and I have corrected my bug.

Comment: Thank you, thank you!!! That was awesome! You have just helped me get a million steps closer to collecting my dissertation data. I will mention  your name in my Acknowledgments section!

Comment: I' d love to read it! I am actually writing a paper for a conference where a lot of data came from web scrapping from newspapers articles made viral through Facebook collectives. Perhaps we could share our works in the future.

Comment: Absolutely! I should be near finished sometime in March 2018. I have much text collecting to pursue (now) and then topic modeling to work through. I would love to read your paper!